# Many issues after upgrading to Android Studio 1.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

So I was using Android Studio 0.8+ (I think 0.86) and everything was working and compiling fine until I upgraded to Android Studio 1.0 and all hell broke lose when trying to compile and execute:

1. No such property: proRunguard

   - Fixed by changing "runProguard = enabled" to "minifyEnabled = true" in the Gradle file
2. com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException

> Error:Execution failed for task ':onz:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Users/JustinLeo/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /Users/JustinLeo/Dropbox/ONz (1)/App Development/Android/onz/onz/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Users/JustinLeo/Dropbox/ONz (1)/App Development/Android/onz/onz/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
>     Error Code:
>       2
>     Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

- added "multiDexEnabled = true" in the Gradle file

  3. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

> Error:Execution failed for task ':onz:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Users/JustinLeo/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --multi-dex --main-dex-list /Users/JustinLeo/Dropbox/ONz (1)/App Development/Android/onz/onz/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/maindexlist.txt --output /Users/JustinLeo/Dropbox/ONz (1)/App Development/Android/onz/onz/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Users/JustinLeo/Dropbox/ONz (1)/App Development/Android/onz/onz/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
>     Error Code:
>       3
>     Output:
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (com.amazonaws.javax.xml.stream.StaxErrorReporter$1) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (com.amazonaws.javax.xml.stream.XMLReaderImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (com.amazonaws.javax.xml.stream.xerces.util.SecuritySupport12$1) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (com.amazonaws.javax.xml.stream.xerces.util.SecuritySupport12$2) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (com.amazonaws.javax.xml.stream.xerces.util.SecuritySupport12$3) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (com.amazonaws.javax.xml.stream.xerces.util.SecuritySupport12$4) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$4) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$5) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$6) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$2) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$3) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       (org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$1) that doesn't come with an
>       associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
>       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>           at com.android.dx.cf.code.RopperMachine.run(RopperMachine.java:609)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator$SimVisitor.visitConstant(Simulator.java:691)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.code.BytecodeArray.parseInstruction(BytecodeArray.java:772)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.simulate(Simulator.java:94)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.processBlock(Ropper.java:787)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:742)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:349)
>           at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:137)
>           at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:729)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:82)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:505)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:332)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:243)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

- Added the following:

dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

4 Now it compiles and executes! But as soon as the app starts it crashes before even showing the first activity:

> 12-12 11:06:31.529  19499-19499/com.commonextract.fitmalaysia E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.commonextract.fitmalaysia.LoginFragment$4', referenced from method com.commonextract.fitmalaysia.LoginFragment.
>   12-12 11:06:31.529  19499-19499/com.commonextract.fitmalaysia W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3315 (Lcom/commonextract/fitmalaysia/LoginFragment$4;) in Lcom/commonextract/fitmalaysia/LoginFragment;
>   12-12 11:06:31.539  19499-19499/com.commonextract.fitmalaysia E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.commonextract.fitmalaysia.LoginFragment$3', referenced from method com.commonextract.fitmalaysia.LoginFragment.onSessionStateChange
>   12-12 11:06:31.539  19499-19499/com.commonextract.fitmalaysia W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3314 (Lcom/commonextract/fitmalaysia/LoginFragment$3;) in Lcom/commonextract/fitmalaysia/LoginFragment;
>   12-12 11:06:31.549  19499-19499/com.commonextract.fitmalaysia E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.commonextract.fitmalaysia.LoginFragment$5', referenced from method com.commonextract.fitmalaysia.LoginFragment.displayOkAlert
>   12-12 11:06:31.549  19499-19499/com.commonextract.fitmalaysia W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3316 (Lcom/commonextract/fitmalaysia/LoginFragment$5;) in Lcom/commonextract/fitmalaysia/LoginFragment;
>   12-12 11:06:31.549  19499-19499/com.commonextract.fitmalaysia E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.commonextract.fitmalaysia.LoginFragment$1', referenced from method com.commonextract.fitmalaysia.LoginFragment.onCreateView
>   12-12 11:06:31.549  19499-19499/com.commonextract.fitmalaysia W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3312 (Lcom/commonextract/fitmalaysia/LoginFragment$1;) in Lcom/commonextract/fitmalaysia/LoginFragment;
>   12-12 11:06:31.549  19499-19499/com.commonextract.fitmalaysia W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41789d58)
>   12-12 11:06:31.559  19499-19499/com.commonextract.fitmalaysia E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.commonextract.fitmalaysia, PID: 19499
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.commonextract.fitmalaysia.LoginFragment$4
>               at com.commonextract.fitmalaysia.LoginFragment.(LoginFragment.java:346)
>               at com.commonextract.fitmalaysia.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.java:104)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
>               at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5321)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2806)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2241)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:805)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 10
        versionName '1.0.11'
        applicationId 'com.commonextract.fitmalaysia'
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':libs:facebook')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:21.0.3'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-2.0.5-s3.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-2.0.5-core.jar')
}
```

And my file structure:

[image: file structure]

Sorry for the long post, but I wanted to detail every step in case there was a problem in between. I  really don't know what's the problem now since I did not modify anything in my codes prior to upgrading. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Looks like your proguard is setup wrong :-/ It removed more classes than expected. Might want to look into MultiDex if you are hitting the 65k limit

Comment: I did add the line multiDexEnabled = true though in step 2

Comment: Oh sorry, the formatting is pretty confusing.